# number of round subset of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ has the same parity as n

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$. Its subset is called a *round subset* if no-empty and the average of its elements is an integer. Prove that the number of round subsets of the set $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ has the same parity as $n$.

Comment: Done, now what?

Comment: What do you mean by done?

Comment: I mean to imply to you that this is not a 'do my homework for free' service, and that you need to show the effort that you've made in attempting to answer this question on your own if you're expecting others to make an effort for you.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

- Show that if $A\subseteq[n]$ is round and has average $m\notin A$, then $A\cup\{m\}$ is round.
- Show that if $A\subseteq[n]$ is round and has average $m\in A$, then either $A=\{m\}$, or $A\setminus\{m\}$ is round.

Say that a subset of $[n]$ is *very round* if it is round and has more than one element.

- Use the first two points to show that $[n]$ has an even number of very round subsets.
- Combine this with the observation that every $1$-element subset of $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is round to get the desired result.